# Move Category Description to Before Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layered-navigation, sidebar

I have managed to move my category description to the left sidebar, however it is stuck at the bottom, how can I move it to above the layered navigation.

```
<move element="category.description" destination="sidebar.main" before="-"/>
```

I have tried using catalog.leftnav but that doesn't seem to work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this one out, if anyone else has the same issue, here is my answer:

```
<move element="category.description" destination="sidebar.main"/>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="category.description" />
```

I add this to Layout Update XML on the category pages I want to change.

Hope this helps anyone